# Sharing Redux state to other clients doesn't work when stringified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am directly sending a redux state from one client to another by simple converting objects to string and sending over websocket and received and parsing and dispatching to store.

The issue is if object is like this :

```
"{"type":"some_action","uid":"1","updates":{"attributes":{"content":["hello"]}}}"
```

then it works fine but if let's say object is like this :

[image]

then i get the error on other client : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20with%20keys%20%7Btype%2C%20key%2C%20ref%2C%20props%2C%20_owner%7D&args%5B%5D=

which states object are not valid as react client. Here is stringified version of object in image.

```
{
  "type": "some_action",
  "uid": "1",
  "updates": {
    "attributes": {
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "em",
          "key": "_domReact2",
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "children": {
              "type": "strong",
              "key": "_domReact1",
              "ref": null,
              "props": {
                "children": "a"
              },
              "_owner": null
            }
          },
          "_owner": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please see that props can be nested here. I tried a hack which is created a null React.creatElement and merged two object so that i have missing '$$typeof' key and it worked, but i am looking for better way or answers from the community. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have react elements in the state that you're trying to send?

Comment: @DonovanM Yes from the object it looks like and i am using middleware.

Comment: You can't convert a react component into JSON. All of the methods would be destroyed and you would lose all internal state. What are you trying to accomplish by sending components?

Comment: I am trying to store them in localstorage so that its in same state after reload. But it gives an error. I am using this : https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage

Comment: Oh I see. It might be possible if you only send the values in the state.

Comment: So may be there is someway to create element from the object i have already in localstorage i can use. I think if i apply all the redux states linearly it shouldn't affect the internal states right?

Comment: Yes, you *might* be able to create the same thing from what's in your redux state, but there isn't enough information for me to know that for sure. You should be able to dispatch the same actions over websocket and get the same result. You just can't send a whole react component. :)

Comment: I am happy to provide extra information you may require for this question.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert a react component or an object with a function to a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`, you will loose all functions and only properties will be kept. So when converting back to an object using `JSON.parse()` the object could not work properly. Example below.

A better way could be to pass the react state as JSON (or part of it) to another client, and use the reducer to update client state. When the state will be update your React component should be too.

Example:

Send a message using websocket which contains object redux action serialized in JSON. In redux an `Action (Object)` is a plain object describing the change that makes sense for your application and can be serialized.
From the client which receive the message, parse the JSON so you can recreate the action object. Now re-dispatch your action so the reducer can modify the state in that client. For this use `dispatch(action)` which will trigger a state change.

```js
let test = {
   a(){
    alert('hi')
   },
   b: 'prop'
};

let str = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(str);

let obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj); // a has been lost
```

Comment: How would i fix that, for eg can i create an element and assign these props which seem to work fine but seems hackish to me.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I believe the proper way could be to pass the state or part to it using websocket, and have the react component update itself, instead of passing the react component itself as it won't work because how `JSON.stringify()` works.

Comment: Example is much appreciated if you can help, I thought redux actions will take care of this basically these are redux actions and I am sending those to clients. I also tried local storage middleware to preserve state which also didn't work may be because that also stringifies and parse from local storage.

Comment: Thanks again :), Though I am doing the same thing I am serializing a redux action which is described in the question above and parsing that in other client and dispatching using store.dispatch method but I get an error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner}).

Though not all redux action has content value with react element some simply has a string which works fine. Both the objects in question above are redux action.

Comment: I think you are serializing a react component in your action, action should contain only properties with value, when instead I see in your image also Symbol and so on.

Comment: Ok, so it's the issue at underlying redux action then. I will check the code.
Though If I extend this received object using react.createElement('') it works fine but will have to do with nested props too which is ugly. Thanks for you time in replying though :)

Comment: @AbhishekSharma you are welcome, if you found my answer useful please remember to accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, thanks I will, i am looking if there is any alternate to what i might be doing. :)